# Finding an expression for the diameter of a circle.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The figure shows two circles of radius $1$ that touch at $P$. [image: A circle][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozhVv.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozhVv.png) $T$ is a common tangent line; $C_1$ is the circle that touches $C$, $D$, and $T$; $C_2$ is the circle that touches $C$, $D$, and $C_1$; $C_3$ is the circle that touches $C$, $D$, and $C_2$. This procedure can be continued indefinitely and produces an infinite sequence of circles $\{C_n\}$. Find an expression for the diameter of $C_n$.

Comment: Kiss precise circles   $ 1/R= 1/R_1 + 1/R_2  \pm \dfrac {2} {\sqrt  {R_1R_2}} $  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll work with the radii instead of the diameters. Obviously, any diameter is twice the corresponding radius. Now, note from the figure below that the triangle $OAB$ is rectangular at $A$.

[image]

Thus,
$$
\overline{OA}^{\,2} + \overline{AB}^{\,2} = \overline{OB}^{\,2}
$$

So,
$$
(\underbrace{1}_{\overline{OA}})^2 + (\underbrace{1 - R_1}_{\overline{AB}})^2 = (\underbrace{1 + R_1}_{\overline{OB}})^2
$$
which gives you

> $$
> R_1 = \frac{1}{4}
> $$

Similarly, by making $B$ be the centre of the ever-smaller circles, you should be able to see that
$$
(\underbrace{1}_{\overline{OA}})^2 + (\underbrace{1 - 2R_1 - 2R_2 - \cdots - 2R_{n-1} - R_n}_{\overline{AB}})^2 = (\underbrace{1 + R_n}_{\overline{OB}})^2
\qquad(1)
$$
for $n > 1$. Now define

> $$
> S_{n} \equiv \sum_{k\,=\,1}^{n}R_k
> \qquad (n \ge 1)
> \qquad(2)
> $$

so that $(1)$ can be written as
$$
1 + (1 - 2S_{n-1} - R_n)^2 = (1 + R_n)^2
\qquad(3)
$$
for $n > 1$. However,
$$
(1 - 2S_{n-1} - R_n)^2 =
1 + 4S_{n-1}^2 + R_n^2 - 4S_{n-1} - 2R_n + 4S_{n-1}\,R_n
$$
and $(3)$ gives
$$
1 + 1 + 4S_{n-1}^2 + R_n^2 - 4S_{n-1} - 2R_n + 4S_{n-1}\,R_n =
1 + 2R_n + R_n^2
$$
which can be simplified to
$$
(1 - 2S_{n-1})^2 = 4(1 - S_{n-1})R_n
$$
so

> $$
> R_n = \frac{1}{4}\frac{(1 - 2S_{n-1})^2}{(1 - S_{n-1})}
> \qquad (n > 1)
> \qquad (4)
> $$

This gives $R_n$ in terms of the radii of only the circles with indices smaller than $n$ so it's very amenable to a recursive calculation. For example, we already have $R_1 = 1/4$. Then $S_1 = 1/4$ and $R_2 = 1/12$. Then $S_2 = 1/3$ and $R_3 = 1/24$. Then $S_3 = 3/8$ and $R_4 = 1/40$, and so on.

Computing a few more values in succession, it's easy to discern the pattern:

> $$
> S_n = \frac{n}{2(n+1)}
> \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
> R_n = \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}
> \qquad (n \ge 1)
> $$

That these satisfy $(2)$ and $(4)$ can be easily proven by induction on $n$.

Comment: Your derivation looks fine to me, but what would I know about [Apollonian](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y43/PM2Ring/LineCirc2.png) [Circles](http://i2.photobucket.com/albums/y43/PM2Ring/Apollo5.png)? :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Clearly you'd know *a lot*. *Very* nice pictures!

Comment: Thanks, wltrup! Keep up the good work.

Comment: Very nice and intuitive writeup plus pics +1. Makes reading and understanding a pleasure

Comment: @Shailesh Thanks!

Comment: @wltrup O!, You have answered and i was unaware of it. Actually i came up at these results quiet earlier before you had answered, but i forgot to inform you about that. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @user258250 No worries, not a waste of my time. I enjoy solving geometry problems. If you don't mind, though, I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @wltrup Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

here is another way to look at this problem. we will use inversion on a circle.

let me set up the coordinate system. we will choose the coordinate system so that the initial circles have centers at $(1, 0), (-0,1)$ and the horizontal line touching these circle and $C_1$ is $y = 1.$ the mirror circle is the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1.$  a point $(0, y)$ on the $y$-axis gets reflected to $(0,1/y).$

the images of the initial two circles are the parallel lines $y = \pm 1/2.$ the image of the circle $C_1$ has a diameter the line connecting $(0,1), (0,2).$  in the same way the image of the circle $C_n$ has a diameter the line connecting $(0,n), (0,n+1).$

reflecting these points, we find that $C_1$ has a diameter connecting the points $(0,1), (0, 1/2)$ and therefore the length of the diameter is $1-1/2 = 1/2$ and the diameter of $C_n$ is $\frac1n - \frac1{n+1} = \frac1{n(n+1)}.$

Comment: Very nice solution! +1

Comment: @wltrup, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Notice, the radius say $r_1$of circle $C_1$ is given by the formula (see [derivation](http://www.academia.edu/10798008/Mathematical_Analysis_of_Three_Externally_Touching_Circles_Derivations_of_inscribed_and_circumscribed_radii_for_three_externally_touching_circles_)) $$\color{red}{r_1=\frac{ab}{(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2}}$$ setting radii $a=b=1$ of larger identical circles, we get  $$r_1=\frac{1\cdot1}{(1+1)^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Now, the radius $r_2$ of circle $C_2$ externally touching the circles $C$, $D$ & $C_1$ is given by the standard formula (see [derivation](http://www.academia.edu/10798008/Mathematical_Analysis_of_Three_Externally_Touching_Circles_Derivations_of_inscribed_and_circumscribed_radii_for_three_externally_touching_circles_)) 
$$\color{red}{r_2=\frac{abc}{2\sqrt{abc(a+b+c)}+(ab+bc+ca)}}$$ Setting the values of $a=1, b=1, c=r_1=\frac{1}{4}$, we get radius of circle $C_2$ as follows $$r_2=\frac{1\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{4}}{2\sqrt{1\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{4}\left(1+1+\frac{1}{4}\right)}+1\cdot1+1\cdot \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1}=\frac{1}{12}$$

Similarly, 
the radius $r_3$ of circle $C_3$ externally touching the circles $C$, $D$ & $C_2$ is calculated by setting the values of $a=1, b=1, c=r_2=\frac{1}{12}$ in the above standard formula as follows $$r_3=\frac{1\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{12}}{2\sqrt{1\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{12}\left(1+1+\frac{1}{12}\right)}+1\cdot1+1\cdot \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}\cdot 1}=\frac{1}{24}$$ Thus, continuing the same procedure, we can calculate radius of any circle $C_n$ using above standard formula.

Comment: Clearly one of us has made a mistake since our answers don't match. I can't see anything wrong with my derivation but, if it there is something wrong with it, I'd appreciate someone pointing it out to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was some error in substituting the values.

Comment: Glad to se that our solutions are now in agreement.

Comment: Actually, there was  a minor mistake in substitution which created much confusion  among users & they went on down-voting without observing it. Any way, our answers are in agreement. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think the reason for the down-votes is more likely to be that your solution - even thought it's correct - is a little obscure. It uses results that are derived somewhere else in a very complicated manner, and it's hard to follow because of all the 1's all over the place. It also doesn't provide a full answer to the question asked because you stopped at $r_3$.